# Proving Derivative at 0 exists

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I'm really struggling on this question.  I've thought about it for a long time now but I can't seem to figure it out.  I know I am supposed to use the Mean Value Theorem in $[0,h]$ with $h>0$ and use the Mean Value Theorem in $[h,0]$ with $h<0$.

Attempt: I applied the definition of mean value Theorem for both of these and get:

There exists c such that $f'(c)=f(h)-f(0)/h$.  There exists d such that $f'(d)=f(0)-f(h)/-h$.  $f'(c)$ clearly equals $f'(d)$, which implies c=d=0.  Thus f'(0) exists.  I'm not sure if this is correct, but how would I conclude it equals L?

I know that there is some theorem that $f\in C[a,b],  $  f is differentiable in [a,b).  Then if $\lim\limits_{x \to a+} \ f'(x)\in R$, then $L=f'(a)$.

I think then the fact given in the question that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \ f'(x)\ =L$, would imply that $f'(0)$ equals L from this theorem, and hence we are finished.

Is this correct?  I'm not sure if I did it correctly, but have given my best attempt.  Any help would be much welcomed.

Comment: What is the "Hint"?

Comment: To use the Mean Value Theorem, which I explained that I attempted to do

Comment: I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct for the problem.

Comment: @HansLundmark I disagree. This question is a proof verification as well, and he did not proceed the same way than the person on your link.

Answer (score 1):

For the interval $[0,h]$, the MVT states that there is some $x \in (0,h)$ such that

$$
f'(x) = \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
$$

Let $h \downarrow 0$. Then $x \downarrow 0$ because it's in $(0,h)$ and, and we have

$$
\lim_{x \downarrow 0} \ f'(x) = f_+'(0)
$$

where the RHS follows from the definition of a right-hand derivative. Also, the LHS is equal to $L$, as it was given. Thus $f'_+(0) = L$.

A similar argument for the interval $[-h,0]$ yields $f_-'(0) = L$, from which it follows that $L = f'_+(0) = f_-'(0) = f'(0)$.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this is pretty similar to my attempt?

Comment: Does that mean my attempt is correct?

Comment: I think you had the right idea, but your problem is that you set up the equations such that your $h$ in the first (for $c$) is positive, and negative in the second one (for $d$). You can't directly compare the two expressions because the $h$'s are different.

Comment: I see makes sense, the hint which is cutoff in the question uses [h,0] with h<0 which is why I did that instead of [-h,0].  Thanks.

Comment: Kenni. Nice.A s a result we can conclude that f'(x) is continuous at x=0.

Answer (score 1):

The part : $f'(c)=f'(d) \implies c=d=0$ is not very clear.

Consider for example $f(x)=x^3$, then $f'(x)=f'(-x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. That does not imply $x=-x$.

In addition, avoid talking about differentiability on closed or semi-closed intervals. $f'(a)$ is not well defined on $[a,b)$. I am not saying that the theorem you are talking about does not exist at all, but it probably does not exist the way you are describing it.

The proof given by Ken Wei is the one you are supposed to do, according to the hint.

Comment: I see makes sense.  I realized I made a mistake.  Mean Value Theorem implies there exists a c in the open interval (a,b) so that the instantaneous slope=average slope.  I will use your guys suggestions and try to come up with a better proof.  Thanks.

Comment: I thought c is an element of [0,h] and d is an element of [h,0] implying c=d=0, but I realize this is wrong.